# Elasticsearch, aggregate by array field's value

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

My documents looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        'user_id': 1,
        'search_text': 'hi',
        'searched_departments': ["dep4", "dep5", "dep6"]
    },
    {
        'user_id': 1,
        'search_text': 'hi there',
        'searched_departments': ["dep4", "dep6"]
    },
    {
        'user_id': 5,
        'search_text': 'I like candy',
        'searched_departments': ["dep4", "dep11", "dep999"]
    },
    {
        'user_id': 2,
        'search_text': 'hi',
        'searched_departments': ["dep4", "dep6", "dep7"]
    }
]
```

I want to do an aggregation that returns the count of each department,
so in this case I want my end result to be something like:

```json
{
"dep4" : 4,
"dep6" : 3,
"dep5" : 1,
# and so on
}
```

my mapping:

```
{'mappings': {'properties': {'date': {'type': 'date'},
                             'searched_departments': {'type': 'text'},
                             'search_text': {'type': 'text'},
                             'user_id': {'type': 'text'}}}
```

Comment: Please add index mapping so it will easy to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not get aggregation on text type of field (if you still want to generate aggregation on text type of field then field should be enable with `fielddata` parameter to `true`). For getting aggregation, you can define `searched_departments` field as [multi field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html) with keyword and text both type.

Below is Sample Mapping:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {
            "date": {
                "type": "date"
            },
            "searched_departments": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                    "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                    }
                }
            },
            "search_text": {
                "type": "text"
            },
            "user_id": {
                "type": "text"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then below query will give you your expected result:

```
POST index_name/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "dept_count": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "searched_departments.keyword",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```